# "unindent does not match any outer indentation level" error at the line "return gpa_sum"

Tags: python-3.x

```
def courses(x):
    gpa_sum = 0
    for i in range(x):
        grade = input("Enter your Letter Grade: ")
        weight = int(input("Is it weighted?(1 = yes, 0 = no) "))
        gpa_sum = gpa_sum + GPAcalc(grade, weight)
    return gpa_sum
```

"unindent does not match any outer indentation level" error at the line "return gpa_sum" (little arrow points to the 'm' at the end) Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check for a mixture of tabs and spaces. They may look indented correctly but still be wrong.  (And then stick to tabs or spaces, preferable spaces.  If your editor doesn't allow you to configure your tab settings, get a new editor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code wasn't indented properly

```
def courses(x):
  gpa_sum = 0
  for i in range(x):
      grade = input("Enter your Letter Grade: ")
      weight = int(input("Is it weighted?(1 = yes, 0 = no) "))
      gpa_sum = gpa_sum + GPAcalc(grade, weight)
  return gpa_sum
```

Comment: @Cool-bagel If the solution worked, please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Sorry, I', still kinda new to this website :p